# How to get model element for textnode in ckeditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I want to show a special popup which allows an user to edit a specific custom attribute, if the user double clicks on an element of a specific type.

Let us for example say for the a element, but I would prefer a solution which works on all custom text nodes.

I have this code:

this.listenTo(viewDocument,'click',(event,data) => {
const viewElement=data.target;
...
}

And that gives me the view element the user clicked on. But I can't find out how to map this view element to an model element, in order to allow me to update/change/set my custom attribute.

There is editor.editing.mapper.toModelElement but that don't work for text elements such as a.

As an alternative, is there a method which allows me to set a custom attribute/property directly on the view, in a way that still get it stored in the model so it don't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

for text nodes you'll need the view parent

```
const viewTarget =
    editor.editing.view.domConverter.findCorrespondingViewText(textNode);
  return editor.editing.mapper.toModelElement(viewTarget.parent);
```

this snippet takes a textNode from dom, finds it's corresponding view, when we map to model, it'll have to be for it's parent which will be usually a paragraph or other model items such as list item and so on

in your case it'll be something like

```
this.listenTo(viewDocument,'click',(event,data) => 
{ const viewElement=data.target; 
  const modelItem = editor.editing.mapper.toModelElement(viewElement.parent)
})
```